# "createlang: command not found" in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get musicbrainz database on my MacOS 10.12 from https://bitbucket.org/lalinsky/mbslave/overview

I have 10.5 version of postgres.

In the link, third step needs a command which says "createlang plpgsql musicbrainz"

I get "createlang: command not found" error for that.

Can someone help me with this? I am completely new to postgres.

Comment: Iam using postgres but in window but maybe the first thing always error in execute command using postgres is path..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Quote from the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-10.html)

> Remove createlang and droplang command-line applications (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> These had been deprecated since PostgreSQL 9.1. Instead, use CREATE EXTENSION and DROP EXTENSION directly.

Additionally there is no reason to use `createlang plpgsql` (or `create lang plpgsql`) at all anymore.

Since Postgres 9.0 PL/pgSQL is automatically available in any newly created database.

So just skip that line.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `createlang` is installed:

```
ls $(dirname $(which psql))
```

The listing should include `createlang`.

If it isn't installed you might execute equivalent commands in `psql`. Something similar to this:

```
> psql musicbrainz
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

musicbrainz# CREATE LANG plpgsql;
```

Comment: This answer is much more helpful than the accepted one for other languages such as `plperl` that are not enabled by default.